# procedure to explore an analytic view in SAP HANA

Tags: stored-procedures, hana, measure, dimension

I am creating a procedure that can explore an analytic view given one dimension, one measure and a filter (where clause)

```
drop procedure dynamicExploration;

create procedure dynamicExploration(in currentMeasure double, in filter_string 
varchar(100), out dataSubset dataExplorationOutputType)
language sqlscript as

begin
      dataSplitby = select CITY as ID, SUM(:currentMeasure) as SUM_MEASURE from
     _SYS_BIC."package/analyticView" Group by CITY;

  --dataSubset = APPLY_FILTER(:dataSplitby, :filter_string);
  dataSubset = select * from :dataSplitBy;
end;
```

where dataSubset is a data type defined as follows:

```
drop type dataExplorationOutputType;
create type dataExplorationOutputType as table("ID" varchar(100), "SUM_MEASURE" double);
```

but I am getting this error, could your please check what's wrong;

> Could not execute 'create procedure dynamicExploration(in currentMeasure double, in
>
> filter_string varchar(100), out ...' in 166 ms 8 µs .
>
> SAP DBTech JDBC: [266] (at 200): inconsistent datatype: only numeric type is available
>
> for aggregation function: line 4 col 36 (at pos 200)

I also tried to define `currentMeasure` as varchar but still getting the same error.

What I am trying to achieve eventually is to create a stored procedure that can help another procedure to select a data subset based on a set of given parameters defined by the user: dimension, measure and filters.

```
drop procedure dynamicExploration;

create procedure dynamicExploration(in currentDimension varchar(100), in currentMeasure   double, in filter_string 
 varchar(100), out dataSubset dataExplorationOutputType)
 language sqlscript as

 begin
  dataSplitby = select :currentDimension as ID, SUM(:currentMeasure) as SUM_MEASURE from
  _SYS_BIC."package/analyticView" Group by :currentDimension;

  dataSubset = APPLY_FILTER(:dataSplitby, :filter_string);
 --dataSubset = select * from :dataSplitBy;
 end;
```

I have already created a procedure to do this kind of dynamic exploration based on dynamic SQL, a feature that is not recommended. What I am looking for is a better solution/idea to do this kind of dynamic exploration of an analytic view (data cube).

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will have to construct a dynamic SQL and execute it with the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command. I know it's not recommended, but your use case requires it. Make sure to protect yourself from SQL injection, e.g. by checking the name of the dimension that is passed into your wrapper procedure against a list of "allowed" dimensions

Comment: hi, I updated my post to present what I am trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: ok, I think I got it. Dynamic SQL is the only way to achieve this. "not recommended" does not mean "never do it" (why would SAP HANA support execution of dynamic SQL when you must never use it), it means "use wisely and only when really required")...